# Cultivation or martial arts manhwa

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character is isekaied into the video game were he is a  side/support character that dies further down road. He wants to prevent that from happening. The main character does have a game system as well. He is semi-overpowered at the start.

The time setting is modern-day, he is a high school student, and his parents are dead, I believe. He moves in with friend of the family and she is a female principal/teacher. She has two daughters, I think; one is a class-president-type girl that wields a sword, and the other one is a NEET (someone who is unemployed and not studying).

The time frame of the manga was early 2000's. I believe it was a site that got shut down.